# cout with this_thread::sleep_for?

Tags: c++, multithreading, cout

I'm testing using `this_thread::sleep_for()` to create an object that acts similarly to `cout`, except when printing strings it will have a small delay between each character. However, instead of waiting 0.1 seconds between each character, it waits about a second then prints it all at once. Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

class OutputObject
{
    int speed;
public:
    template<typename T>
    void operator<<(T out)
    {
        std::cout << out;
    }
    void operator<<(const char *out)
    {
        int i = 0;
        while(out[i])
        {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(speed));
            std::cout << out[i];
            ++i;
        }
    }
    void operator=(int s)
    {
        speed = s;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    OutputObject out;
    out = 100;
    out << "Hello, World!\n";
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Edit: CoryKramer pointed out that std::flush is required for it to act in real time. By changing `std::cout << out[i];` to `std::cout << out[i] << std::flush;`, I solved my problem!

Comment: You likely just need to [`std::flush`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/flush) within the `while` loop

Comment: Remember that output to `std::cout` is *buffered*.

Answer (score 3):

Streams have buffer, so `cout` won't print text before you flush stream, for example `endl` flushes stream and adds `'\n'` also call to `cin` automatically flushes buffered data in stream. Try to use this:

```
while(out[i])
{
   std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(speed));
   std::cout << out[i];
   std::cout.flush();
   ++i;
}
```